# Flexbox: align right several elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an HTML-structure:

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item item--right">4</div>
    <div class="item item--right">5</div>
  </div>
```

And styles:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
}
```

I want items 1, 2 and 3 to be on the left, and items 4 and 5 on the right.
I was trying to solve this problem using `align-self: right`:

```
.item--right {
  align-self: right;
}
```

But it didn't help.
[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/316akt85/) my fiddle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `align-` properties are for aligning elements on the _cross_ axis, not the main axis. It would have an effect if you had `flex-direction: column` on the parent. // Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, it has a pretty comprehensive explanation ...

Comment: Have you tried `float: right;`?

Comment: @Justinas `float` does not work with Flexbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the first element that needs to be pushed right and apply `margin-left:auto`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item item--right">4</div>
  <div class="item item--right">5</div>
</div>
```